# How to stop CSS roll in animation at some point?

Tags: html, css

I want to create "roll in" effect with image of 8-ball. I want this animation to load on page load and to end then ball reaches text layer that's in the middle (of revolution slider).

On codepen I found similar thing that I have used and achieved result at some point but animation goes infinite. The question is, how to achieve that ball stops when it reaches text layer?

This is what I've got so far:

```css
.circle {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* Animation to spin and move the sphere */
  -webkit-animation: spin 1000ms linear infinite, moveLeftToRight 5s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 1000ms linear infinite, moveLeftToRight 5s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: spin 1000ms linear infinite, moveLeftToRight 5s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 1000ms linear infinite, moveLeftToRight 5s linear infinite;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}


/* Spinning the sphere using key frames */

@-ms-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}


/* Move sphere from left to right */

@-moz-keyframes moveLeftToRight {
  0% {
    left: -100px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 50%;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes moveLeftToRight {
  0% {
    left: -50px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 50%;
  }
}

@keyframes moveLeftToRight {
  0% {
    left: -100px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 50%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveLeftToRight {
  0% {
    left: -100px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="circle" src="https://i.imgur.com/1KfVzUa.png" />
```

Comment: euh ..remove `infinite` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the fill-mode to freeze the animation state at the end of the animation.

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

`forwards` leaves the animation in the state of the last frame

`backwards` leaves the animation at the start